# OpenVPN/SSH tunnel to see client's other interfaces

Tags: networking, openvpn, vpn, tunneling

Using OpenVPN or SSH tunneling (or a combination), how could I connect 2 LAN networks together?

Here is a better (more detailed) explaination with OpenVPN as an example:

One OpenVPN client (we will call client 1) is connected to LAN A, also connected to the OpenVPN server

This OpenVPN server sits in the cloud (ex: Digitalocean)

Another OpenVPN client (client 2) is connected to LAN B, also connected to the OpenVPN server

How would I be able to see other devices on LAN A from client 2 with OpenVPN, effecively connecting client 2 to LAN A?

Comment: Are you trying to connect them at an Ethernet level, or just IP? OpenVPN can do both (IP level would certainly perform better, but sometimes you need them to appear as on the same Ethernet segment)

Comment: @derobert I really only need to be able to talk to other devices based on their IP (and be able to scan ports for service detection), so I think IP level would work fine if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set up routing. Make sure IP forwarding is enabled on the VPN server and the clients (I presume the clients are the default gateways for the two LANs, that's easiest). Also, it's easiest to run two OpenVPN instances on the VPN server, one for each client (point-to-point). Just give them different ports to run on.

Then you just need to add "route" directives to your OpenVPN configs. Using 192.168.1.0/24 as a stand-in for the first network and 192.168.2.0/24 for the second:

ptp-first.conf (not full config, just a few things that might be different from a normal point-to-multipoint client VPN):

```
mode p2p
dev-type tun
dev first_vpn
ifconfig 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 # note NOT on either network
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
```

ptp-second.conf:

```
mode p2p
dev-type tun
dev second_vpn
ifconfig 192.168.0.3 192.168.0.4 # note NOT on either network
route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Remember the client configurations will need the "ifconfig" addresses in the opposite order.

You can find a lot more information, example configs, etc. by searching with terms like "openvpn routing".

Comment: will this be the same for clients that aren't the default gateways? Should have mentioned that, sorry

Comment: @danthegoodman If the clients aren't the default gateway, you have to somehow get all the traffic for the other LAN directed to them. You could add a route on the default gateway to do that (probably results in extra traffic on the LAN, as it first goes to the default gateway then goes to the VPN client), or on all the machines on the LAN (a PITA, but avoids the duplicated traffic). Especially on e.g., gigabit Ethernet, the duplicated traffic is unlikely to matter, so I'd go with the first option.